# nav_header_main in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

[this is the screenshot ][1]Can you help me please, the header(email and an image of profil) is               not found, this the code nav_header_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profil" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"         
        android:src="@drawable/profil" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="GPS Tracking"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="aaaa.com" />

</LinearLayout>`
```

main_pro.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout          
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:context=".tracking.MainPro">
<include
layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrrawerLayout>
```

the error :Error:(2) No resource identifier found for attribute 'context' in package 'com....'

> 08-12 16:57:52.849 5438-5438/.gps.tracking E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                          Process: gps.tracking, PID: 5438
>                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{.gps.tracking/.gps.tracking.MainPro}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
>                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                           Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
>                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
>                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
>                                                                              at gps.tracking.MainPro.onCreate(MainPro.java:31)
>                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
>                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308) 
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602) 
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
>                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
>                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249) 
>                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106) 
>                                                                              at gps.tracking.MainPro.onCreate(MainPro.java:31) 
>                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451) 
>                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308) 
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602) 
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
>                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                                           Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
>                                                                              at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:184)
>                                                                              at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:227)
>                                                                              at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.(NavigationView.java:152)
>                                                                              at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.(NavigationView.java:88)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600) 
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
>                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249) 
>                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106) 
>                                                                              at .gps.tracking.MainPro.onCreate(MainPro.java:31) 
>                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451) 
>                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308) 
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602) 
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
>                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675) 
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700) 
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
>                                                                              at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:184) 
>                                                                              at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:227) 
>                                                                              at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.(NavigationView.java:152) 
>                                                                              at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.(NavigationView.java:88) 
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600) 
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
>                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249) 
>                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106) 
>                                                                              at com.sifast.gps.tracking.MainPro.onCreate(MainPro.java:31) 
>                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451) 
>                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308) 
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602) 
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
>                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                                           Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f020043 a=-1 r=0x7f020043}
>                                                                              at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3412)
>                                                                              at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
>                                                                              at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:133)
>                                                                              at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:123)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600) 
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675) 
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700) 
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
>                                                                              at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:184) 
>                                                                              at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:227) 
>                                                                              at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.(NavigationView.java:152) 
>                                                                              at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.(NavigationView.java:88) 
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600) 
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
>                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249) 
>                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106) 
>                                                                              at gps.tracking.MainPro.onCreate(MainPro.java:31) 
>                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451) 
>                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308) 
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602) 
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
>                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>   08-12 17:00:00.674 5438-5438/gps.tracking I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5438 SIG: 9

Comment: Please give more details

Comment: What is the problem can you please *elaborate* more.

Comment: the menu exist but the header of the layout dosen't appear, i can't inderstand the problem

Comment: Do you get the problem in java file ?

Comment: Show the code where you make use of this XML file, and describe what you mean by "not found". You cannot retrieve the views with `findViewById()`?

Comment: @Ammouna1993 please use `edit` to update your post. Don't add code in comment as it is no readable

Comment: @ piotrek1543 :ok sorry

Answer (score 3):

The `NavigationView` internally uses a `RecyclerView` to display the headers and menu items. This causes the activity to not find any views in the header, as the `RecyclerView` dynamically loads the views (that's the whole purpose of it).

However, the support library has a method for getting the header view, as documented in the [`NavigationView` API reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html):

> [`getHeaderView(int index)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html#getHeaderView(int)): Gets the header view at the specified position.

So the following piece of code should get the profile `ImageView` and the email `TextView`:

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
ImageView profileView = (ImageView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.profil);
TextView emailView = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

---

**Edit:** Based on the stack trace you provided the core issue is the following (`@drawable/profil` is apparantly not a valid drawable or doesn't exist):

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path)

Comment: thank you for your reply .I try it but i find an error: cannot find symbol method getHeaderView(int)

Comment: Please make sure that you are using the latest version (24.1.1 at the time of writing)!

Comment: yes this is the problem , i don't use it . i use 22.0.1

Comment: i edit the code , please how can can i resolve this error to appear the header layout

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot? I'm not sure I properly understand the issue. Thanks!

Comment: thank you for your reply .i add the screenshot  any solution please !

Comment: Try removing the `app:context` part. I'm not aware of any attribute that is called `context`...

Comment: i remove it , but the header doesn't exist. i think that tools:headerLayout should be app:headerLayout , but the application was crashed .the error :android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

Comment: Yes, you definitely need to use `app:headerLayout`! The `tools` prefix is only used for Android Studio previews.

Comment: Can you post the full logcat output, please?

Comment: The error occurs when inflating the `ImageView` of your header. What is the `profil` drawable? Is it a vector drawable?

Comment: Something is wrong with your image drawable. Is it a xml file or a raw image? If it's a xml drawable please post it. Thanks.

Comment: In which folder/path is that image located? What Android version are you testing this on?

Comment: android 2.1.2 , the folder was drawbale  : profil.png

Comment: Try to put it in a `drawable-nodpi` folder. I remember some issues with the default `drawable` folder.